# PowerShell ExecutionPolicy prompt while registry value 'bypass'

Tags: windows, powershell

I need to run scripts without user input. But recently my scripts have started to require input for the ExecutionPolicy.

I'd set the ExecutionPolicy previously via
`Set-ExecutionPolicy` for all scopes to 'Unrestricted'. However, this was still leading to user input being required.

I've manually set the registry key for ExecutionPolicy to `bypass` but it's still using the unrestricted setting on all scopes.

It's not domained, so isn't pulling any GPOs from our DC.

The local GPO for execution policy `allows all scripts`.

I've tried setting the ExecutionPolicy to bypass using the command `Set ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy bypass -Scope LocalMachine -Force` which leads to the error `setting is overridden by a policy defined at a more specific scope`

I then tried `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy bypass -Scope  MachinePolicy -Force` and it gave me the error

`ExecutionPolicy must be set through Group Policy` but as mentioned it's set to allow all scripts.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to set the Registry via `Set-ItemProperty` and not through regedit.

As soon as I ran this command
`Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell -Name ExecutionPolicy -Value ByPass` it showed correctly when listing `Get-ExecutionPolicy`

Unless there was an issue with capitalisation as it was set to 'bypass' rather than 'ByPass'